# What does the left angle bracket after a while loop mean in bash?

Tags: bash, loops

The following is from /etc/init.d/functions on RHEL. I'm trying to figure out what the `__pids_var_run()` function does when I came across this while loop.

```
            while : ; do
                    read line
                    [ -z "$line" ] && break
                    for p in $line ; do
                            if [ -z "${p//[0-9]/}" -a -d "/proc/$p" ] ; then
                                    if [ -n "$binary" ] ; then
                                            local b=$(readlink /proc/$p/exe | sed -e 's/\s*(deleted)$//')
                                            [ "$b" != "$binary" ] && continue
                                    fi
                                    pid="$pid $p"
                            fi
                    done
            done < "$pid_file"
```

Could someone explain what `while : ; do ; ... done < "$pid_file"` does? More specifically, the last part after `done`, as the rest of it more or less makes sense.

Comment: It means the same thing as it does after any command.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means that any command in the loop that reads something from stdin will  read from the given file (instead of the keyboard, for example).

In this case in particular, the loop uses `read line` to read a single line from stdin, so when you redirect from `$pidfile` it effectively reads the file line by line.

To further read about redirections, here's an [Illustrated redirection tutorial](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/redirection_tutorial) which is recommended by [this Bash Guide](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide) by [Lhunath](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Lhunath) and [GreyCat](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/GreyCat).

Comment: In means to take stdin from the file.  It has nothing at all to do with a keyboard.  Often, stdin is associated with a keyboard, but it is a mistake to conflate the two.

Comment: Sure, I didn't know at what level to explain it.

Comment: Technically, it specifies standard input for the `while` compound command itself, from which any command in the body inherits its own standard input.

Comment: not only the *programs* inside the loop but also the shell builtins (i.e. `read`)

Answer (score 3):

I see that this quesiton is already answered (I cannot comment because I did a bounty), but I think you should check out this site when you get a chance:

http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001

This guy (or gal) really dives in to proper and improper syntax with examples.